# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven- >plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli)

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, eclipse-mars, sonarlint-eclipse

Hi everyone this is my first question here on StackOverflow, I hope someone of you could help me in this problem:
I'm trying to configure my java project on Eclipse (Mars 8.2) for SonarQube detection but when I run my configuration the output notify me this error:

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-26T01:13:06+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 45M/93M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project cg4: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.report.ActiveRulesPublisher: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules: Server is not available: http://localhost:9000/: Fail to request http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=cs-sonar-way-89394&p=1&ps=500: timeout: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project cg4: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.startComponents(ProjectScanContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Server is not available: http://localhost:9000/
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.loadFromServerFirst(WSLoader.java:197)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.load(WSLoader.java:148)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.loadStream(WSLoader.java:124)
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.load(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:61)
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:104)
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:65)
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.provide(ActiveRulesProvider.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=cs-sonar-way-89394&p=1&ps=500
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:201)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:143)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:132)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:65)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader$3.load(WSLoader.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader$3.load(WSLoader.java:81)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.loadFromServer(WSLoader.java:225)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.loadFromServerFirst(WSLoader.java:188)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:79)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:909)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$300(HttpEngine.java:93)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:894)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:748)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:277)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:198)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
    ... 115 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I've read the link that is mentioned after the Error notification but I didn't find the solution to my problem, could anyone help me?

Comment: _Fail to download libraries 
from server: Connection refused_. You've got an invalid URL or some other issue. Could be behind a proxy if you're at school. There are a bunch of possibilities.

Comment: Didn't read everything. You're trying to connect here.  SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000]  You do have a server running on that port, right?

Comment: Now I'm not at school, so this isn't a problem of proxy.

I'm trying to configure the project to link it to SonarQube analisys but when I specify the correct "run configuration" I have those line showed in the Console output

Comment: I edit the ask with details so I hope someone could help me with this problem

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory. There is an attempt to connect to a server on your local machine at port 9000. This connection fails. What server are you running at port 9000?

Comment: Sonarqube, but I've already solved my problem, thanks

Comment: @DanieleUboldi If you've solved your problem then you should post an answer to your question, to share it with the community.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was simply due to the instability of the server; I didn't put Sonar in the "Running mode" so when the "Run configuration" tryed to connect to the server this was offline, not reacheble. 
So before everything if you have installed Sonarqube, you have to (Windows instructions) go inside the folder called "sonarqube x.y version" and execute the file .bat located inside it into admin mode.